# Error page not being used on exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

When an exception is thrown on my MVC4 (.NET) application, the error page is shown.

My web.config file has

```
<system.web>    
    <customErrors mode="On"  defaultRedirect="~/Error/" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"  />
</system.web>
```

But, in the controller for my About Page, I am diving by 0 (to test it). Naturally, an exception is thrown but it does not redirect me to my Error controller. Instead, the page shows:

> Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request.

My ErrorController is:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{  
       return View();
 }
```

And my routes are

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

And my View is empty:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "There was a fault.";
}
```

A look online shows it is most likely the web.config, but mine does *appear* to be correct.

I could understand this message if the Error controller or the Error View had faults!

Please note, I have used customErrors for MVC many times before, on the same server, so I'm lost as to why this is occurring.

What should I be doing?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: The web page responds with `Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request` @ckv . If in debug mode, it obviously shows me Visual Studio's compilers message (invalid attempt to divide by 0)

Comment: Can you show controller and action piece of code and your routing code.

Comment: @ckv sorry for delay, I have updated !